# Can I use math ceil with input string in Java?

Tags: java, ceil

Is it possible to make this output in Java?
Using Looped statements while asking for input Grades for each student then use Ceiling to identify who has the highest grade.

```
Student Number            Grades

Student 1                  _
Student 2
Student 3 
Student 4 
Student 5
Student 6
Student 7
Student 8
Student 9
Student 10
```

The student with the highest Grade is: (e.g) Student 8

Comment: I don't think that Ceiling does what you think it does, and this smells suspiciously like a homework assignment. We are not here to do your work for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Not sure how you intend to use ceil. How about keeping track of who has the highest grade currently, at the end of the loop you will have the student with the highest grade.

Comment: grades will be inputted by the user one by one

Comment: Can ceiling only be used in one number? or it can be used with multiple numbers like that.

Comment: Look at the *Scanner* class for input and *ceil* is used for rounding up not for comparisons. And, keep track of the current highest grade while looping for input itself.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it's possible.  Now, as @rmlan asked, what have you tried?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Yes I have an idea of using Scanner for input. Its just the ceil, now I know its only for rounding up. Maybe its not possible.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help, I'll just think another way to use that Ceil or any suggestions for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a loop:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
double max = -1; // grades can't be negative
int maxStudent = 0;
double[] grades = new double[10];
for (int i = 1; i < grades.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter grade for Student "+i);
    grades[i] = scan.nextDouble();
    if (grades[i] > max) {
        max = grades[i]
        maxStudent = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.ceil(double a)
```

Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer. So unless you're trying to round up, you won't need ceil. Although to answer the title question, you can use `Math.ceil` on an input string, assuming the string can be parsed into a double.

For instance, these are all true statements:

```
Math.ceil(99) == 99.0
Math.ceil(99.01) == 100.0
Math.ceil(99.99) == 100.0
```

> Can ceiling only be used in one number? or it can be used with multiple numbers like that.

You can not use `Math.ceil` on any sort of collection to find the highest value as you wish to do. Loop through all values an keep track of the highest